# Can't understand the solution of HDU 2823

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, raycasting, convex-hull

The following code snippet was taken from [here](http://blog.csdn.net/crazy852456/article/details/10931959). It is the solution of this problem [HDU 2823](http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/showproblem.php?pid=2823).

```
#define eps 1e-9
double rc(point pp[],point qq[],int n,int m)    
{    
    int q=0;    
    int p=0;    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)     
        if(pp[i].y-pp[p].y<-eps)    
            p=i;    
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)    
        if(qq[i].y-qq[q].y>eps)    
            q=i;    
    pp[n]=pp[0];    
    qq[m]=qq[0];    
    double tmp,ans=1e99;    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)    
    {    
        while((tmp=cross(pp[p+1],qq[q+1],pp[p])-cross(pp[p+1],qq[q],pp[p]))>eps)    
            q=(q+1)%m;    
        if(tmp<-eps)    
            ans=min(ans,dist_p_to_seg(qq[q],pp[p],pp[p+1]));    
        else    
            ans=min(ans,dist_seg_to_seg(pp[p],pp[p+1],qq[q],qq[q+1]));    
        p=(p+1)%n;    
    }    
    return ans;    

}
```

`pp[]` and `qq[]` are two different convex hull. `p` is the highest point of `pp` convex hull and `q` is the lowest point of `qq` convex hull.

I can't seem to understand this line:

```
while((tmp=cross(pp[p+1],qq[q+1],pp[p])-cross(pp[p+1],qq[q],pp[p]))>eps) 
    q=(q+1)%m;
```

What is he trying to achieve?

Comment: Be careful when asking about snippets of code. The value of `eps`, for instance, is quite important - as is its use. Are you familiar with the common use of an "epsilon value"?

Comment: Woh! I like math, but not when it's in such long strings like that:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function cross(a, b, c) is finding the determinant of the following matrix,

```
| a.x a.y 1 |
| b.x b.x 1 |  = 2 * A
| c.x c.y 1 |
```

Where A is the **signed** area of the triangle a, b, c.
The sign of the determinant also tells us if 3 points are oriented clockwise or conter-clockwise. [see here for an explanation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html)

Let's rewrite like this,

```
triA ← cross(pp[p+1],qq[q+1],pp[p])
triB ← cross(pp[p+1],qq[q],pp[p])

// This is equivalent to,
// just to make it a bit clearer
triA ← cross(pp[p], pp[p+1],    qq[q+1])
triB ← cross(pp[p], pp[p+1],    qq[q])
```

So it checks if the triangle formed by *one side of the hull pp* with the lowest point on `qq` is smaller than the triangle formed by the same side and next highest point from qq.

If yes, select the next point in qq as `q` and continue. —i.e. select a `q` so that the perpendicular distance of `q` from side `<p, p+1>` is minimized.

[image]

Once this is locally minimised for a given side `<p, p+1>`, repeat this for all sides of `pp`. At each step keep the minimum distance between the *current* sides.

This is a somewhat *shaky* way of finding the minimum separation between two convexhulls. The intuition is correct —correct in the sense that it is simple to understand (the idea, *not* the code in question), quite general for convex polygons, and very useful a variety of problems (see the reference below); however, I have a feeling that this can be written in a much more efficient and easy to understand way.

The intuition behind such ideas is nicely illustrated in this paper 
["Solving Geometric Problems with the Rotating Calipers"](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/cs97/s08/pdf/calipers.pdf)
-- Toussaint G.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
and just curious, how did you made that geo drawing?

Comment: Np. Adobe Illustrator.